# Limit of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n+1} = 0.9 x_n + 500$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $x_{n+1} = 0.9 x_n + 500$ with $x_0 = 10$. The limit of the sequence, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n$, seems to be about 5000 when I try it in a spreadsheet.

How can I prove that the limit converges and that 5000 is correct? Also, is there a way to write an equation for $x_n$ that is non-recursive so that elements of the sequence can be calculated directly?

Comment: If the limit exists then $L=.9L+500$, so you just need to argue existence.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I think that gives me enough information to figure the rest out. Thanks!

Comment: The solution for when I inevitably look this up again in 5 years: $x_n = (x_0 - 5000) (0.9)^n + 5000$, where $5000 = \frac{500}{1-0.9}$